# JsDoc typechecks for JS files in Neovim

Tags: neovim, lsp, eslint

Is it possible in Neovim to use JsDoc for typechecking of javascript files?
Right now I use default LSP configurations for eslint and tsserver provided by lspconfig:

```lua
-- init.lua
require('lspconfig').tsserver.setup({})
require('lspconfig').eslint.setup({})
```

It works but seems to provide typechecks only for typescript files.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `// @ts-check` comment in the file. This will trigger type checking on normal JS files with TypeScript, as well as with JSDoc.

Example without `// @ts-check`:

[image: with comment]

Example with `// @ts-check` (notice line 4):

[image: without comment]

Here is an example with JSDoc being checked:

[image: jsdoc example]

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :( do you have any particular settings for tsserver LSP maybe? Or tsconfig.json/jsconfig.json files?

Comment: Also, maybe LSP plugins are doing the trick for you here?

Comment: Hmm, I use `lsp-zero` for my lsp setup and not `lspconfig` directly, maybe that's related? The file I showed you is not in a TS project, it was a blank directory. My LSP config was otherwise nothing special.

Comment: Oh, it seems to work but not completely. Look at this silly example: https://i.imgur.com/7ziwYoZ.png VSCode on top and vim on the bottom. `return` statement is highlighted as an error in VSCode because return type of the function as written in the JsDoc is `{number}` while in the code it can return `null`. Vim doesn't seem to capture that even if I add `// @ts-check` on the top line of the file.